# PHP Try-Catch or ExceptionHandling does not seem consistent in shudown_handler

Tags: php

I am looking to understanding the nature of the register_shutdown_function.

case 1:

```
    \register_shutdown_function(function() { 
        try{ 
            throw new \Exception();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex; //print the exception
        }
    });
```

case 2:

```
    \register_shutdown_function(function() { 
        try{ 
            $r = new \ClassThatDoesNotExist();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }
    });
```

In Case 1 the exception is caught by the `catch` block.
In Case 2 the exception occurs but doesn't enter the `catch` block (PHP just exits). However, if Xdebug is ON, then Xdebug catches / displays it.

I understand Case 2 is a Fatal Error based Exception - because that is what it shows.
I am also aware that an exit call inside the shutdown function preempts PHP process and exits right away.

Case 2 doesn't to go to the exception handler (this however makes sense).
But Case 2 seems to behave like an exit call inside shutdown - this does not!!!.

Does a fatal Error in shutdown block just terminate the PHP process?
Is there more documentation other than the manual?

I am using PHP 8.1

Thanks in Advance